# Angular UI router and $stateChangeError - strange resolve loop

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The app I'm writing is using the resolve property in the main UI router state. 
It tries to resolve to a list of things, using a factory that uses $http.
So I was trying to implement error handling, I changed my server to return a 404 status, and added thus lines:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event) {
  $state.go('404');
});
```

as Nate Abele explained here: [Angular UI router handling 404s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281351/angular-ui-router-handling-404s)

Now the app do try to change the state to my 404 state, but a very strange loop occurred. The app keep trying to resolve the failed factory from the resolve property. 
Haven't figured up why until now.

Any suggestions ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post a little more code to help us out?  We def. need to see the `resolve`  and 404 state definition, and anything else you think would, help us.  The question you are referencing has no approved answers.  C

Comment: Does your `404` state, by any chance, descend from the main state that contains the resolve?

Comment: you forgot to add `event.preventDefault()`