# UI-Router: change template on missing states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to "set" the view when a user accesses a missing state? I wanted the 404 handler to only some notice if the user tried to access a non-existent page instead of a redirecting the user.

Something similar to [Github's 404](https://github.com/thispagedoesnotexist).

Comment: Use the `otherwise`. Here is a link to another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281351/angular-ui-router-handling-404s

Comment: I think I've found the answer. Will try, then answer my question if nobody does.

Comment: if state is missing we **cannot** change the template - which belongs to state. We really need to navigate to `otherwise` def... where should be state, where should be proper template. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25591908/1679310)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `@cshion` said you can catch `$stateNotFound` and go to another state
or something you want.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function ($rootScope, $state) {
  $rootScope.$on("$stateNotFound", function (event, unfoundState, fromState, fromParams) {
        $state.go('my404state');
  });
}]);
```

This will work only by invoking `$state.go('missingstate');` **but if the user types a fake url not work.** so is more suitable for testing/debugging purposes.

In the other hand you can redirect the user using `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise`

```
app.config( ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
   function ($stateProvider,   $urlRouterProvider) {
       $urlRouterProvider
           .when('/', [$state, function($state) { $state.go('home') }])
           .otherwise('/notfound');
    }
]);
```

And create a specific state to show 404 not found.

#### EDIT: based on comments.

Another option is to use [`$urlRouterProvider.rule`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#rule-for-custom-url-handling)  for custom url handling

```
app.config(['$urlRouteProvider','MyAuthService', function ($urlRouterProvider) {
  
   $urlRouterProvider
         .when('/', [$state, function($state) { $state.go('home') }])
         .rule(function ($injector, $location) {
               if (MyAuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
                   return "/user/mainpage";
               }
               return $location.path();
          })
         .otherwise('/notfound');
}])
```

[Note that `otherwise` wraps a `rule` that returns the same url that receive.](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/807ec33f1bf6a4103b9da5e674a26c08993c6654/src/urlRouter.js#L102-L110)

Comment: Actually I'm using this approach , but what happens when we are managing authenticated users, if type a fake url, a better option is redirect to user's main page so in that case, we need to manage fake states( or locations) inside app.run I think.

Comment: Does $state.go change the URL / location ($window.location)?

Comment: yes, [$state.go()](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options)

Answer (score 1):

You could  check state change events in your app.run function..
something  like this..

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
  $rootScope.$on("$stateNotFound", function (event, unfoundState, fromState, fromParams) {
        //manage state not found
  });
});
```

Source: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki