# Is there an event that fires when a Videogular video 404s?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, videogular

I'm just trying to display an error message instead of my video when the video 404's (right now it attempts to load endlessly). I thought the best solution was indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281351/angular-ui-router-handling-404s?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I don't know that videogular fires an event at all upon 404.

If an event does fire I would just flag a bool to show the div:

controller constructor

```
error404 = false;
$rootScope.$on('$VideogularError', function(event) {
      error404 = true;
    });
```

HTML

```
<videogular ng-hide="error404">
  ...
</videogular>    
<div ng-show="error404">
   404 error occurred!
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears there's a `vg-error` callback you can take off of your `videogular` element.

```
<videogular ng-hide="error404" vg-error="error404 = true">
  ...
</videogular>
```

Comment: I actually have something like that applied, but I believe that pertains to Videogular having an error. In this case, it's the source file that is corrupted causing a 404.

Comment: well it sounds like you need to ask the project for an enhancement request.

Comment: That can be arranged