# firebase 404 page configuration in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I try to add a 404 page into my angularjs project which is hosted on firebase servers. I created a custom 404 page and added following code:

```
function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider)
{
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/pages/errors/error-404');
}
```

Now it works but I am missing something because when I check in the browser's network panel the status code is "200" but it should be "404".

What should I do for that?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about angularjs but normaly you have to set the response-code server-sided and angularjs ist a frontend framework.

Answer (score 0):

`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` just guides AngularJS that which URL it should navigate to when no URL matches the provider's rules.

This doesn't signify that a resource is not found on the server (which essentially returns 404). To do that, you need to do a lot more including serving this 404 page from the server with 404 as the status code.

Here is a resource to point you in the right direction:

- [AngularJS UI router handling 404s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281351/angularjs-ui-router-handling-404s)